# Null data when passing ArrayList<Integer> through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I'm sure I've missed something stupid, this can't be this hard...

I'm passing an arraylist of integers from one class to another.  Logs show the data is correct in the passing class, but it invariably shows up null in the recieving class.  **All** other intent data is correctly passed.

ArrayList unsavedEditedSets are private class variables.

Please help.

Passing Class segment:

```
holder.returnButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            unsavedEditedSets.add(setPositionChoice);
            Intent i = new Intent(SetEditor.this, DisplayFullWorkout.class);
            i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("use", unsavedEditedSets); 

            Log.d("INIT - OK",""+unsavedEditedSets); // This shows data is in the arraylist

            i.putExtra("subsets", subsetsList);
            i.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(i);      
        } 
    });
```

Catching Class:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> unsavedEditedSets;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_full_workout);

    Intent incomingI = getIntent();
    subsetsList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)incomingI.getSerializableExtra("subsets");
    unsavedEditedSets = (ArrayList<Integer>) incomingI.getIntegerArrayListExtra("use");

    extras = incomingI.getExtras(); 

  Log.d("Incoming - BAD",""+unsavedEditedSets); // This shows null arraylist        
}
```

Tried using a new arraylist right before sending and still get null:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   test.add(12);
   test.add(19);
   i.putExtra("use", test); Log.d("INIT - OK",""+test);
```

Comment: Logs show only:   Init - OK   [1]      and    Incoming - Bad    null

Comment: Try to pass as same "subsets" means SerializableExtra.

Comment: Thank you @Haresh, I originally had it that way and it returned null.  Just tried again, just in case... still null.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `unsavedEditedSets` from the catching class?

Comment: Something going wrong with this unsavedEditedSets variable becz you have to try another demo Integer ArrayList and check what happens.

Comment: shoudln't `extras = incomingI.getExtras();` be called before calling `getIntegerArrayListExtra()` and `getSerializableExtra()`?

Comment: Don't know that it matters @Atif -- but I tried it, and still get null.  I'm missing something here...

Comment: What if you remove `putExtras` and `putExtra("subsets"...)`? Does `extras` contain `"use"` by chance?

Comment: YES!!!!  @Nija!  That was the answer!  putExtras(extras)  was the problem.  I can put everything else in there, but the putExtras line was somehow screwing it up.  Guess I need to go back to the documents to figure this out, but it is working.  Thank you very much.  Please if you can stick this in the answer I'll click it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying to an answer from my comment on the post:

Simplify the code to only pass along the `use` extra that's coming through as null. See if that works. If it does; then add back the `subsets` extra.

It's possible (and based on it working without, likely) that the `extras` object has an extra in with the key `use` already.

Another check would be to change the key from `use` to a new value (`not_used_elsewhere_cause_its_really_long`) and see if the value is successfully passed through when `putExtras` is placed back.

Comment: UPDATE.  Nija's answer got me to the solve, and is likely correct for most people with this problem.  However, in case someone else makes same mistake, my issue here was that I forgot to **implement Serializable** in the passing class.  This was the direct cause of the null item being passed in the _non-serialized_ list that was passed.  Odd way to manifest, and very hard to track.  In the end, was indeed my stupid mistake, but not easy to find.  Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly it should be more along the lines of:

```
Bundle extras = incomingIntent.getExtras();
ArrayList<Integer>  = extras.getIntegerArrayList("key");
```

Comment: Thanks J.Romero.  Still getting same null incoming...  I'd normally blame myself for something stupid, but testing it with the values added directly before the intent seems like it should have worked too...